# Stemming a word using Linux command line

Tags: awk, sed, grep, hunspell

I have a corpus file that I need to compare with another file "vertically" and list unique left-over strings. For example:

`exclude.txt`:

```
ed
s
ing
```

And the second file is:

`corpus.txt`:

```
worked
working
works
tested
tests
find
found
```

Expected output:

```
work/ed,ing,s
test/ed,s
```

The other words (find and found) can also be returned optionally.

I tried like this:

```py
with open ('/home/corpus.txt') as corpus:
    for i in corpus:
        i = i.strip('\n')
        with open ('/home/exclude.txt') as exclude:
            for x in exclude:
                x = x.strip('\n')
                if i.endswith(x):
                    print (x, i, re.sub(r'(.*)'+x, r'\1', i)+'/'+x)
```

The output is something like this...

```
ed worked work/ed
ing working work/ing
s works work/s
ed tested test/ed
s tests test/s
```

As you can see I am not getting expected output. Nor is this Python code useful if the corpus file is large.

---

Here's some slightly less trivial input to test with:

```
$ head -100 exclude.txt corpus.txt
==> exclude.txt <==
works
ed
s
ing
ings

==> corpus.txt <==
worked
working
works
tested
tests
find
found
workings
```

The expected output given the above would be (printing the unmatched words is optional, as is printing matched/unmatched at the start of each line):

```
unmatched find
unmatched found
matched working/s
matched work/ed,ing,s,ings
matched test/ed,s
```

Comment: Obviously, don't read the same static file into memory again and again.

Comment: "As you can see I am not getting expected output." - yes, because your code does not even try to aggregate the words with the same stems, and your `print` statement does not even match the basic format of your expected output. Your tags don't have anything to do with your code either. It looks to me like you have no clue what you are doing and are attempting to use SO as a free code writing service.

Comment: In your sample input/output you should have included a) some of the strings from `exclude.txt` in `corpus.txt` to ensure you don't get null strings output, and b) regexp metachars such as `.` and `*`, typical delimiters such as `/`, and backreference chars such as `\1` and `&`, and any other typically problematic characters  in `exclude.txt` to ensure they're treated literally.

Comment: what should happen to a corpus value like `workings` ? (ie. multiple suffices could apply)

Comment: work/ed,ing,s is creating 3 words worked, working and works. The same way working/s will create workings. I have not mentioned the tag because "hunspell" tag is not popular :)

Comment: Because your sample input is so small and sunny-day you're getting solutions that'll only work for sunny-day cases, you should really put some effort into coming up with an example that we can use to thoroughly test a potential solution. I've given you some examples in comments under your question above and under answers below and it sounds like you've come up with some rainy-day cases too from your comments (e.g. a unicode word).

Comment: **As a starting point** to you creating a comprehensive test case I added some simple sample input/output that has proven to be problematic for some solutions, feel free to do whatever you like with that edit. I'm sure there are more potentially problematic cases, including some cases with all-alphabetic and some with non-alphabetic characters, some of which I added to the example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ lineLgth = length($0) }
NR == FNR {
    suffixes[$0]
    sfxLgths[lineLgth]
    next
}
{
    base = ""
    for ( sfxLgth in sfxLgths ) {
        baseLgth = lineLgth - sfxLgth
        if ( baseLgth > 0 ) {
            sfx = substr($0,baseLgth+1)
            if ( sfx in suffixes ) {
                base = substr($0,1,baseLgth)
                bases2sfxs[base] = bases2sfxs[base] "," sfx
            }
        }
    }
    if ( base == "" ) {
        print "unmatched", $0
    }
}
END {
    for ( base in bases2sfxs ) {
        sub(/,/,"/",bases2sfxs[base])
        print "matched", base bases2sfxs[base]
    }
}
```

The above uses literal string functionality so it'll work even if the strings in either input file could contain regexp metacharacters, backreference characters/strings, typical string/regexp delimiters, escape sequences, or any other potentially problematic characters (the OP may not have all of those cases but others with similar problems reading this in future might).

For example, given this input which tests all of the above occurring in both files:

```
$ cat exclude.txt
works
ed
s
ing
ings
.
*
.*
/
&
'
"
\
\1
\t
```

```
$ cat corpus.txt
worked
working
works
tested
tests
find
found
workings
abacus
formless
impress
stories
amusing
linings
toppings
underlings
x.
x*
x.*
x/
x&
x'
x"
x\
x\1
x\t
```

the above script would produce this output (output sorted just for ease of seeing which words got which suffixes):

```
$ awk -f tst.awk exclude.txt corpus.txt | sort
matched abacu/s
matched amus/ing
matched formles/s
matched impres/s
matched lin/ings
matched lining/s
matched storie/s
matched test/ed,s
matched topp/ings
matched topping/s
matched underl/ings
matched underling/s
matched work/ed,ing,s,ings
matched working/s
matched x./*
matched x/.,*,.*,/,&,',",\,\1,\t
unmatched find
unmatched found
```

I'm also looping on the length of the strings in `exclude.txt` (contents of `suffixes[]`) rather than looping on the actual strings for efficiency.

If we have, say, 10 3-letter words in `suffixes` that we want to match against the last 3 letters of a line from `corpus.txt` then we'd populate our `suffixes` array from exclude.txt and loop through corpus.txt either way but then our options for implementing "check for a match" are (pseudo-code):

a) Compare each suffix from exclude.txt to the last 3 letters on each line from corpus.txt  (this **will loop 10 times** as we have 10 suffixes):

```
NR == FNR {
    suffixes[$0]
    next
}
{
    for ( sfx in suffixes ) {     # loops 10 times
        wordEnd = substr($0,length($0)-length(sfx))
        if ( wordEnd == sfx ) {
            it's a match
        }
    }
}
```

b) Compare the last 3 letters of each line from corpus.txt to all suffixes from exclude.txt at once via a hash lookup (this **will loop 1 time** as all suffixes are 3 chars long in this example):

```
NR == FNR {
    suffixes[$0]
    sfxLgths[length($0)]
    next
}
{
    for ( sfxLgth in sfxLgths ) {    # loops 1 time
        wordEnd = substr($0,length($0)-sfxLgth)
        if ( wordEnd in suffixes ) {
            it's a match
        }
    }
}
```

So I implemented option "b" to only loop 1 time for all suffixes that are N characters long instead of looping N times.

Regarding how much more efficient looping by length is than looping by suffix - for what it's worth, according to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_suffixes there are 392 English language suffixes but 368 of those are in a bell curve between 2 and 7 characters long averaging 61 suffixes per length in that range. So looping one time on a length in that range would save on average about 60 iterations compared to looping on each of the suffixes of that length.

The test for `if ( baseLgth > 0 )` is necessary to not output `<null>/<suffix>` if, say, a word from corpus.txt also exists in exclude.txt.

Tweak it to modify the output format and/or add a variable to control printing the unmatched words if you like as your question isn't clear on how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

[TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
(let ((suffix-regex (flow "exclude.txt"
                      file-get-lines
                      (cons 'or)
                      regex-compile))
      (wh (hash)))
  (with-stream (s (open-file "corpus.txt"))
    (whilet ((w (get-line s)))
      (iflet ((rng (r$ suffix-regex w)))
        (push [w rng] [wh [w 0..(from rng)]]))))
  (dohash (w suffs wh)
    (put-line `@w/@{(reverse suffs) ","}`)))
```

```
$ txr condense.tl
work/ed,ing,s
test/ed,s
```

Compile:

```
$ txr --compile=condense.tl
work/ed,ing,s
test/ed,s
```

Now there is a compiled, faster `condense.tlo`.

If `txr condense` is used (no suffix), it will choose the `.tlo` over `.tl`.

The trick used in this code is to generate a regular expression which matches the word suffixes. This is done by taking the list of words from the file like `("ed" "ing" "s")` and tacking on the `or` symbol with `cons` to produce `(or "ed" "ing" "s")`. This expression is the abstract syntax for the regular expression `ed|ing|s`; we just hand that off to `regex-compile` to produce the compiled regex object. No escaping is required because the string terms in the abstract syntax denote fixed, literal matches.

Comment: getting error Segmentation fault (core dumped) for large corpus file.  But it works very well for small files. Upvoted but not accepted (yet).

Comment: I replaced the code with a version that reads line by line, in case that's the problem. Also, avoid using TXR via Homebrew; that distro produces an unreliable executable.

Comment: Can not accept this answer because it did not return the correct results. It had issues with this unicode character, but awk is treating it correctly. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+094D

Comment: I can't debug it without knowing how that character appears in a specific test case and what problem it causes. TXR treats all text streams as UTF-8 and works with code points, including in regular expressions. So the solution is expected to work over international text even though it's based on ASCII examples. Can you add a sample of your real data to the question?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. TXR output is correct. I did not check thoroughly. Appreciate you help and introduction to the language.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
               {for(k in a) {
                  i=length($1)-length(k); 
                  if(substr($1,i+1)==k) {
                     w=substr($1,1,i); 
                     b[w]=b[w] sep[w] k; 
                     sep[w]=","}}} 
       END     {for(k in b) print k"/"b[k]}' exclude corpus

work/ed,ing,s
test/ed,s
```

Comment: A (unicode) word was listed in stemmed word as well as non-stemmed. This minor issue is not there in the code provided by Ed Morton.

Comment: I started out looping on the suffixes too then realized if `exclude.txt` contained 10 3-letter suffixes that'd loop 10 times per line in `corpus.txt` with only 1 possible match whereas if you loop on the **length** of the strings in `exclude` it'd only loop 1 time per line in `corpus` and immediately have the match or no-match result. I added some blurb about that to my answer.

Comment: You also need to test that the line from corpus is longer than the suffix or you will end up with output like `/suffix` where the base part is a null string. Try adding `works` to `exclude.txt` for example and it'll output `/works` since `works` exists in `corpus.txt`,

Comment: Right! For null root `if(i>0 && substr($1,i+1)==k)` should do.  For long suffix lists reverting the loop/match order makes sense for performance.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#s@\\B&$@/&@p#' file1 |
sed -nf - file2 |
sed -E ':a;N;s#(.*)(/.*)\n\1/#\1\2,#;ta;P;D'
```

The first sed invocation builds a sed script that inserts a `/` between words in an input file that match the desired word endings.

The second sed invocation applies the above sed script and throws away non-matches.

The third sed invocation gathers up duplicate keys (the front half of the word) and concatenates the endings with a `,` separator.

N.B. The solution assumes the input file2 is already sorted. If not a simply sort can be placed between the second and third sed invocations.

Comment: You need a `sort` before the third sed whether the input was sorted or not. Add, say, `workings` to `corpus.txt` then sort it before running the pipeline and you'll see 2 separate output lines for `work` - `work/ed,ing` and `work/s`.

Comment: Also if you then add `ings` to the end of `exclude.txt` it will be missing from the output despite being present in `workings` even if `corpus.txt` is sorted or a pipe to `sort` is added before the 3rd `sed`, and if you then sort `exclude.txt` the output will include a line with 2 `/`s in it, i.e. `work/ed,ing,ing/s,ings,s`